# Is it possible to lift a pair of points on an elliptic $\mathbb{F}_{\!q}$-curve to a pair of short points on an elliptic $\mathbb{F}_{\!q}(t)$-curve?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, abelian-varieties, elliptic-surfaces

Let $E$ be an (ordinary) elliptic curve over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_{\!q}$ of a (quite large) characteristic. For simplicity, suppose that $E(\mathbb{F}_{\!q})$ is a prime group. In addition, let $P_0$, $P_1$ be two non-zero $\mathbb{F}_{\!q}$-points on $E$. Is it true that there is always a lift $\mathcal{E}$ of $E$ over the function field $\mathbb{F}_{\!q}(t)$ and there are independent $\mathbb{F}_{\!q}(t)$-points $P_0(t)$, $P_1(t)$ on $\mathcal{E}$ such that $P_0(\alpha) = P_0$ and $P_1(\alpha) = P_1$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{\!q}$? Of course, I require that $P_0(t)$, $P_1(t)$, and $\mathcal{E}$ are of little heights, i.e., they are independent of $q$.

Comment: How could $P_0(t)$ etc. ever be independent of $q$ when all the data in your problem depends on it?

Comment: Their coefficients may depend on $q$, but their heights are restricted above by a constant.

Comment: You can just choose $\mathcal{E}$ to be the "constant" family, namely $E\times_{\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{F}_q} \text{Spec}\ \mathbb{F}_q(t)$.  Then every $\mathbb{F}_q$-point of $E$ lifts to a "constant" $\mathbb{F}_q(t)$-point of $\mathcal{E}$.

Comment: I require that the points $P_0(t)$, $P_1(t)$ are independent. In particular, they have to be non-torsion. Hence, your approach does not work.

Comment: Fine: take the Weirrstrass model, and use a pencil of plane cubics containing the two points that includes the Weirrstrass model as one member of the pencil.  The intersection matrix shows the lifts are independent.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. Is it always possible to construct in such a way an isotrivial pencil, that is, all its smooth members are of the same j-invariant?